# external email not working exchange and javamail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

Good morning to all,

I was try send external email in my organization does not working for me.When i was try internel email address it working fine.. I am getting exception "invalid mail address 5.1.7 unable to relay"

I am also try send with external email via TELNET. Its working fine in  TELNET.
Exchange 2013 receive connector anonymous relay was enable.

```html
  Properties props = System.getProperties();
         props.put(SMTP_HOST_KEY,smtphost);
         Session session=null;
         System.out.println("Entering into sendSMTPMail=============(props)"+props);   
         MailAuthentication authorization =new EmailManager().new MailAuthentication();
         LogWriter.log("CREATING THE DEFAULT SESSION");
         System.out.println("Entering into sendSMTPMail=============(AUTHORIZATION)"+AUTHORIZATION); 
         System.out.println("Entering into sendSMTPMail=============(authorization)"+authorization);
         System.out.println("Entering into sendSMTPMail=============(session)"+session);
         if(AUTHORIZATION)session = Session.getInstance(props, authorization);
         else session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
         session.setDebug(debug);
         System.out.println("Entering into sendSMTPMail=============(session)"+session);
```

OUTPUT in java :

Send is OK

rcpt is Invaild mail address 5.1.7 unable relay

OUTPUT in TELNET:

Send is OK

rcpt is OK

Help is needed......Please let me know what is problem in javacode or exchange 2013

Thanks.....

Comment: Most of your code is missing above.  Are you actually authenticating to your mail server?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: Thanks Bill Shannon....I was try access without authentication....Is possible using javamail and exchange???

Comment: Please...help needed....

Comment: I don't know whether you can configure Exchange to allow unauthenticated users to send mail that will be relayed outside of the server.  To be clear, this is an issue with the server, not JavaMail.  BTW, what exactly are you trying to show in the OUTPUT above?